# How to start/launch android styled activity faster

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-xml

I'm launching an activity from a broadcastreceiver in the regular way.. (Intent -> StartActivity()..)

The activity is delared like this:

```
        <activity android:name=".AlertActivity"
         android:theme="@style/precall_alert_style" >
```

style/precall_alert_style is inherited from Theme.Dialog and have 1 overridden item.

**It take 1-2 secs to that activity to show up! It's too much..** 
when I launch a toast before the activity the activity starts ok...

**How can I reduce this time?**

Comment: what are you doing in the method `onCreate()` of the new started Activity?

Comment: nothing special, very small amount of code.. no loading, no long processing. I think that the style I applied to that activity is the cause because when I remove the android:theme="@style/precall_alert_style" it works immediately as always. Do you know something about it?

Comment: ok, what is the item that you override in your custom theme?Maybe you have big drawables?

Comment: my style is this:     <resources>
        <style parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" name="precall_alert_style">
            <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        </style>
    </resources>